# Generate BarGraph from DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, graph

So I have a generated a Disease_Data dataframe that has 2 columns, Location and Data (see below).

```
Location    Data
Alabama     30.675
Alaska      27.3917
Arizona     25.825
Arkansas    29.2
California  29.117
Colorado    35.65
```

I wanted to generate a bar graph like below:

[image]

However, when I tried the code below, things did not work and gave an error: KeyError: 'Location'

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
Disease_Data_Loc = Disease_Data['Location']
Disease_Data_Value = Disease_Data['Data']
ax.bar(Disease_Data_Loc ,Disease_Data_Value )
plt.show()
```

Please help, thank you

Comment: `Location` is likely your data's index, you can do: `Disease_Data.plot.bar()`

Comment: @QuangHoang so something like:

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
Disease_Data_Loc = Disease_Data['Location']
Disease_Data_Value = Disease_Data['Data']
Disease_Data.plot.bar(Disease_Data_Loc ,Disease_Data_Value )
plt.show()

??

Comment: No, just `fig,ax=plt.subplots(), Disease_Data.plot.bar(ax=ax)`

Comment: @QuangHoang When I run that code I get 


---> fig,ax=plt.subplots(), Disease_Data.plot.bar(ax=ax)
   

NameError: name 'fig' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, replace the `,` after `subplots` with `;`. Or you can delete the `,` and move `Disease_Data.plot...` into a new line.

Comment: @QuangHoang but FIG is not being defined though? That's the error I am getting, 'Fig' is not defined

Comment: @QuangHoang Nvm, everything has to be done on one line, that fixed things, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Just plot the dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'Location': ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado'],
        'Data': [30.675, 27.3917, 25.825, 29.2, 29.116999999999997, 35.65]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# plot
df.plot('Location', 'Data', kind='bar', legend=False)
plt.ylabel('Cases')
plt.title('Cases of Disease by State')
plt.show()
```

[image]